# how fetch data from 2 classes in parse.com?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

i have this case **Parse.com** and i didn't know how to solve it.

i have three classes.

1. **Videos** have fields [image url,video
   url,description].....
2. **Activities** have fields
   [user(pointer),video(pointer),type(like or comment),content].....
3. **Users** have fields [username,password... ect].....

i want to make query to return data like this.

- image url
- video url
- description
- (if user like this video return yes or no)
- count of likes for this video
- count of comments of this video

i know parse post example for project have something like that, but its **Too complex**!!!

**i attached pic maybe help you.**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **Prashant Sridharan** - *Parser*

I think this query will be way too complicated, if not impossible.

When you render the cell or view for a Video, you will need to do three other asynchronous queries for the like count, comment count, and whether a user likes the video or not. This isn't a bad thing. It makes your app more responsive (even if there are three additional API requests involved). Instead of waiting for one very complicated and potentially long query to finish executing, you can do one query (for the Video), render the view or cell, and then do the other queries in the background and display them whenever they finish.

One thing you should strongly consider is to put the like count and comment count on the Video object itself. Whenever someone likes the video, increment the count. If they unlike it, decrement the count. Same thing with comment. This will eliminate two API requests.